# SSL for AWS EC2 link, is there any faster way? i dont need it in the domain but only on ec2 link public dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, certificate

we are using ec2 link connecting to websites, we are not using domain.. but is there any faster way to setup ssl? please help!

ec2 is where our setup are being done

in amazon cloud there is a free tier.. up to 30gb ssl free, i have been trying to find it and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, as the domain is owned by AWS. You need to have your own domain, and do one of the below:

- Use AWS Certificate Manager with AWS Elastic Load Balancer. (As you don't have the certificate files to configure directly on your web server)
- Generate a certificate using a certificate authority like let's encrypt and configure the SSL on your web server.

If you can't get your own domain you can configure AWS CloudFront add your EC2 public DNS as the origin. Then you can use the distribution URL that supports HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible using AWS Certificate Manager and AWS Elastic Load Balancer. A domain name is required to generate certificates.

Only way to create AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer)
[image]

Create AWS CloudFront with ELB Origin
[image]

then `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`

[image]

After that, you can access your website using a CDN URL with SSL.